# Getting Force Close while running app on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Sometimes getting Force Close message or sometimes, without showing any message my app will close, only showing white plan screen nothing else, but earlier i was getting each and every thing which i have made, but now getting force close problem, code is ok not showing any error, please suggest what step i need to take, and see what logcat report says:-

```
      10-18 13:41:34.202: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
      10-18 13:41:34.202: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
      10-18 13:41:34.202: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
      10-18 13:41:34.202: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1930)
      10-18 13:41:34.202: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
      10-18 13:41:34.202: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.ImageView.
      <init>(ImageView.java:120)
      10-18 13:41:34.202: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.ImageView.
      <init>(ImageView.java:110)
      10-18 13:41:34.212: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
      10-18 13:41:34.212: I/dalvikvm(709): 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
      10-18 13:41:34.212: I/dalvikvm(709): 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
      10-18 13:41:34.212: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView
      (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
      10-18 13:41:34.212: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
      10-18 13:41:34.212: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
      10-18 13:41:34.212: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
      10-18 13:41:34.212: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
      10-18 13:41:34.212: I/dalvikvm(709):  
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
      10-18 13:41:34.212: I/dalvikvm(709):   
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    10-18 13:41:34.226: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    10-18 13:41:34.226: I/dalvikvm(709):   at com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.ListViewCustomAdapter.getView(ListViewCustomAdapter.java:60)
    10-18 13:41:34.226: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
    10-18 13:41:34.226: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
    10-18 13:41:34.226: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
    10-18 13:41:34.226: I/dalvikvm(709):   at 

android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
10-18 13:41:34.226: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:41:34.233: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-18 13:41:34.242: I/dalvikvm(709):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 13:41:34.242: A/libc(709): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 709 (tions.catalogue)
10-18 13:42:21.142: E/Trace(745): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-18 13:42:21.751: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 2% free 8102K/8259K, paused 37ms, total 41ms
10-18 13:42:21.832: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.458MB for 8910016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:21.921: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 1% free 16801K/16967K, paused 30ms+5ms, total 87ms
10-18 13:42:22.751: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 1% free 16801K/16967K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
10-18 13:42:22.912: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.579MB for 20052016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:23.042: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 1% free 36383K/36551K, paused 34ms+28ms, total 123ms
10-18 13:42:23.742: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 29039K, 77% free 9083K/38407K, paused 55ms, total 56ms
10-18 13:42:23.742: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.064MB for 2250016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:23.881: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 71% free 11280K/38407K, paused 29ms+18ms, total 136ms
10-18 13:42:23.881: D/dalvikvm(745): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
10-18 13:42:23.982: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3174K, 79% free 8106K/38407K, paused 87ms, total 87ms
10-18 13:42:23.992: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.461MB for 8910016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:24.082: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 57% free 16807K/38407K, paused 30ms+18ms, total 90ms
10-18 13:42:24.712: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 57% free 16807K/38407K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
10-18 13:42:24.773: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.584MB for 20052016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:24.881: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 36389K/38407K, paused 39ms+9ms, total 113ms
10-18 13:42:25.471: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28284K, 78% free 8706K/38407K, paused 62ms, total 63ms
10-18 13:42:25.471: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.869MB for 1382416-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:25.591: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 74% free 10056K/38407K, paused 23ms+18ms, total 119ms
10-18 13:42:25.591: D/dalvikvm(745): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
10-18 13:42:25.801: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1950K, 79% free 8339K/38407K, paused 70ms, total 71ms
10-18 13:42:25.801: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.702MB for 534616-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:25.872: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 77% free 8860K/38407K, paused 26ms+8ms, total 66ms
10-18 13:42:25.872: D/dalvikvm(745): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
10-18 13:42:25.922: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 232K, 78% free 8633K/38407K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
10-18 13:42:25.931: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.976MB for 8910016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:26.072: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 55% free 17334K/38407K, paused 78ms+8ms, total 134ms
10-18 13:42:27.002: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 55% free 17334K/38407K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
10-18 13:42:27.032: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 36.099MB for 20052016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:27.192: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 36916K/38407K, paused 73ms+20ms, total 156ms
10-18 13:42:27.822: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28283K, 75% free 9612K/38407K, paused 52ms, total 53ms
10-18 13:42:27.822: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.581MB for 2250016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:28.011: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 70% free 11809K/38407K, paused 75ms+19ms, total 189ms
10-18 13:42:28.011: D/dalvikvm(745): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
10-18 13:42:28.092: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 977K, 72% free 10839K/38407K, paused 50ms, total 51ms
10-18 13:42:28.112: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.130MB for 8910016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:28.253: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 50% free 19540K/38407K, paused 74ms+20ms, total 140ms
10-18 13:42:29.172: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 50% free 19540K/38407K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
10-18 13:42:29.172: I/dalvikvm-heap(745): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 20052016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:29.232: D/dalvikvm(745): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 50% free 19531K/38407K, paused 55ms, total 56ms
10-18 13:42:29.232: E/dalvikvm-heap(745): Out of memory on a 20052016-byte allocation.
10-18 13:42:29.232: I/dalvikvm(745): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
10-18 13:42:29.232: I/dalvikvm(745):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a14568 self=0x2a00b9e0
10-18 13:42:29.232: I/dalvikvm(745):   | sysTid=745 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073870640
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   | schedstat=( 6322252531 1424837307 387 ) utm=585 stm=47 core=0
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1930)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
10-18 13:42:29.242: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.ListViewCustomAdapter.getView(ListViewCustomAdapter.java:60)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:42:29.253: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-18 13:42:29.262: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:42:29.262: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:42:29.262: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
10-18 13:42:29.262: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
10-18 13:42:29.262: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
10-18 13:42:29.262: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:42:29.262: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:42:29.262: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-18 13:42:29.271: I/dalvikvm(745):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 13:42:29.282: A/libc(745): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 745 (tions.catalogue)
10-18 13:42:35.582: E/Trace(758): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-18 13:42:36.222: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 2% free 8102K/8259K, paused 55ms, total 59ms
10-18 13:42:36.292: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.458MB for 8910016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:36.432: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 1% free 16801K/16967K, paused 81ms+6ms, total 139ms
10-18 13:42:37.172: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 1% free 16801K/16967K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
10-18 13:42:37.321: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.579MB for 20052016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:37.482: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 1% free 36383K/36551K, paused 74ms+24ms, total 157ms
10-18 13:42:38.161: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 29039K, 77% free 9083K/38407K, paused 55ms, total 56ms
10-18 13:42:38.161: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.064MB for 2250016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:38.362: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 71% free 11280K/38407K, paused 75ms+19ms, total 191ms
10-18 13:42:38.562: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3174K, 79% free 8106K/38407K, paused 188ms, total 189ms
10-18 13:42:38.572: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.461MB for 8910016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:38.712: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 57% free 16807K/38407K, paused 73ms+19ms, total 137ms
10-18 13:42:39.262: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 57% free 16807K/38407K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
10-18 13:42:39.292: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.584MB for 20052016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:39.451: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 36389K/38407K, paused 73ms+18ms, total 155ms
10-18 13:42:40.002: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28284K, 78% free 8706K/38407K, paused 54ms, total 55ms
10-18 13:42:40.012: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.869MB for 1382416-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:40.182: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 74% free 10056K/38407K, paused 74ms+17ms, total 168ms
10-18 13:42:40.182: D/dalvikvm(758): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
10-18 13:42:40.372: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1950K, 79% free 8339K/38407K, paused 47ms, total 48ms
10-18 13:42:40.372: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.702MB for 534616-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:40.491: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 77% free 8860K/38407K, paused 75ms+9ms, total 125ms
10-18 13:42:40.491: D/dalvikvm(758): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
10-18 13:42:40.552: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 232K, 78% free 8633K/38407K, paused 29ms, total 30ms
10-18 13:42:40.572: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.976MB for 8910016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:40.712: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 55% free 17334K/38407K, paused 73ms+20ms, total 137ms
10-18 13:42:41.632: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 55% free 17334K/38407K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
10-18 13:42:41.663: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 36.099MB for 20052016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:41.812: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 36916K/38407K, paused 74ms+18ms, total 151ms
10-18 13:42:42.452: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28283K, 75% free 9612K/38407K, paused 53ms, total 54ms
10-18 13:42:42.452: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.581MB for 2250016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:42.652: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 70% free 11809K/38407K, paused 74ms+18ms, total 189ms
10-18 13:42:42.732: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 977K, 72% free 10839K/38407K, paused 49ms, total 50ms
10-18 13:42:42.742: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.130MB for 8910016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:42.882: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 50% free 19540K/38407K, paused 73ms+9ms, total 139ms
10-18 13:42:43.802: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 50% free 19540K/38407K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
10-18 13:42:43.802: I/dalvikvm-heap(758): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 20052016-byte allocation
10-18 13:42:43.862: D/dalvikvm(758): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 50% free 19531K/38407K, paused 53ms, total 54ms
10-18 13:42:43.862: E/dalvikvm-heap(758): Out of memory on a 20052016-byte allocation.
10-18 13:42:43.862: I/dalvikvm(758): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
10-18 13:42:43.862: I/dalvikvm(758):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a14568 self=0x2a00b9e0
10-18 13:42:43.862: I/dalvikvm(758):   | sysTid=758 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073870640
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   | schedstat=( 6298623943 1113168855 340 ) utm=594 stm=35 core=0
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1930)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-18 13:42:43.872: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.ListViewCustomAdapter.getView(ListViewCustomAdapter.java:60)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:42:43.882: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
10-18 13:42:43.892: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-18 13:42:43.902: I/dalvikvm(758):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-18 13:42:43.912: I/dalvikvm(758):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 13:42:43.912: A/libc(758): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 758 (tions.catalogue)
```

Comment: Should check this line `at com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.ListViewCustomAdapter.getView(ListViewCustomAdapter.java:60)`

Comment: You are getting an OutOfMemory exception while trying to allocate 20MB! See `"10-18 13:42:43.862: E/dalvikvm-heap(758): Out of memory on a 20052016-byte allocation."`

Comment: so please tell me what i need to do?

Comment: Are you using image in your listview?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comments: It seems as though you need to either reduce the size/quality of your images or otherwise implement some sort of paging mechanism so that not all of the images are in memory at once.

Comment: Thanks Mike T i reduced the size of my images and now my app is working smoothly, and also thanks to Sumant,Yul,David and Black to view and reply

Answer (score 0):

If you are using List view to show images then try to use Lazy List which will reduce image size also will load images when you are scrolling.